# Custom word-embeddings in gensim

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I have a word embedding matrix (say M) obtained of order V x N where V is the size of the vocabulary and N is the size of each word vector. I want the word2vec model of gensim to initialise its word embedding matrix with M, during training. I am able to load M in the word2vec format using
gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_file)
but I don't know how to feed M into the gensim word2vec model.

Answer (score 1):

The Gensim `Word2Vec` model isn't designed to be pre-initialized with outside vectors, so there's no built-in helper methods.

But of course since the source is available, and all objects can be modified by your direct tampering, you can still change/replace its usual (random) initialization with anything of your own choosing, wiht a little effort.

Specifically, you'd first create a `Word2Vec` model using the constructor *without* yet supplying any training corpus. (If you supply a corpus, it will automatically do the next two `build_vocab()` and `train()` steps for you, and you don't want that.)

Then, you'd perform the necessary `.build_vocab()` step, allowing it to survey your training text data to discover its vocabulary with word-frequencies, and perform its usual model initialization:

```
model.build_vocab(corpus)
```

At this point, *before* doing any other training, you can tamper with the model to replace its random-initialization of words with your alternate word-vectors, as from the vectors you've loaded. If your other vectors are in the `KeyedVectors` variable `loaded_kv`, this could be as simple as:

```
for word in loaded_kv.index_to_key:
    if word in model.wv:
        model.kv[word] = loaded_kv[word]
```

Note that if your `loaded_kv` includes words that aren't in the `corpus`, or too rare (appear fewer than `min_count` times) in the `corpus`, the `model` will not have allocated a space for those vectors – as they won't be used in training – and they won't be part of the final model.

If for some reason you need them to be, you should ensure a sufficient number of valid usage examples of those words appear inside the `corpus`. You shouldn't add them to the `model` in a ways that changes the total number of vectors in `model.wv` after `.build_vocab()`, because the model is not expecting that sort of change, and errors/undefined-behavior are likely.

(You also shouldn't simply force extra words that *aren't* in the real training data into the model, because while they will remain unchanged through training, all other words will continue to be adjusted through training – meaning any words that weren't also incrementally adjusted, in an interleaved fashion, along with the rest may wind up essentially "incompatible" with the word-vectors that were co-trained in the same full model.)

After you've modified the model's initialization to match your preferences, continue with normal training, something like:

```
model.train(corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
```